# Execute multiple steps in a single named task

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and building my first playbooks now, in one of my plays I am wanting to ensure all the pre-requisite for an application are in place before installing, one of these prereqs includes some custom scripts that will need to be present in the home directory of the application user, I want to know if I can stack multiple tasks (hoping that is the right term) like so:

```
 - name: Check for file and move to /home/user with correct owner and permission
   stat: path=/path/to/{{ item }}
   register: {{ item }}_stat
   command: mv /path/to/{{ item }}  /home/user/{{ user }}
   file: path=/home/user/{{ item }} state=file mode=0755 owner=user group=group
   when {{ item }}.stat.exists
   with_items:
      - file1
      - file2
      - file3
```

I can break this out into multiple tasks/steps and have, but I would like to keep the playbook a lean as possible for when i move it into the approproate role.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Each task may serve one module only.

It's possible to put "subfunction" tasks into a separate file and loop *include_tasks*. For example

```
- name: Check for file and move to /home/user with correct owner and permission
  include_tasks: loop-tasks.yml
  loop:
    - file1
    - file2
    - file3 

$ cat loop-tasks.yml
- stat:
    path: "/path/to/{{ item }}"
    register: result
- block:
    - command: "mv /path/to/{{ item }} /home/user/{{ user }}"
    - file:
        path: "/home/user/{{ item }}"
        state: "file"
        mode: "0755"
        owner: "user"
        group: "group"
  when result.stat.exists
```

(not tested)